# How to create a per-user Startup folder shortcut in a per-machine installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am installing an application using WiX 3 for all users (property ALLUSERS=1). I would like to create a shortcut to my application in the current user's Startup folder. How can I override the ALLUSERS=1 for my Startup folder shortcut only?

I am using the WiX Shortcut element:

```
<Shortcut Id="MyAppShortcut" Directory="StartupFolder" ... />
```

but the "StartupFolder" resolves to the 'All Users' Startup folder because of the per-machine installation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Installing the shortcut only for the current user doesn't seem like a good idea: what if I install your software under an account I only use for administrative tasks such as installing software? Because I try to follow best practices and [Don't Run as Administrator](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/the-windows-security-epidemic-dont-run-as-an-administrator.html)!

If you're trying to run a single instance of the software in the background for the whole system, then you probably should write your software as a [Windows Service](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWindows_service&ei=Fho6Tc2IF8Gj8QOVxMCcCA&usg=AFQjCNEa8Be6_z5NglP8TQjQqHf1AVR8lA&sig2=OHlS3uO32gWDT-1SSIyd3Q) instead of creating startup shortcuts. Wix has support for [installing a service](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_serviceinstall.htm).

If you want a UI component to configure/manage the service to live in the tray, then you can then still install a shortcut for a separate executable to the *All Users* start up folder. That way all users can interact with the service, but the service itself is launched only once.